# How to put image to appear after clicking button in windows store app XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

So im trying to develop a windows store app with C#. After you click a button, few images should appear. So what should I insert here on this method? I cant find any reference online.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to make images appear
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whr the images are how many to appear. Show some code which image ur talking about ??????

Comment: The page is currently empty and I've added only a button. And I need that button to put some images to the page. I have absolutely no idea how to go from here? It should go like dynamic different images shows up when you press buttons.

Comment: u can also use other controls with back ground image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your images are `image1` and `image2`.
Add them into grid and initialize their visibility to collapsed.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    image1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    image2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Then add these lines to your function as shown below.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    image1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    image2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few different ways. You can either "turn on" images that are already part of the layout, or dynamically add some images from the backend. I assume you're new to this, so I'll give you the most straightforward example of turning on an image.

Xaml

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Text="Toggle Images" Click="OnClick" />
        <Image Source="MyImage1.png" x:Name="Image1" />
        <Image Source="MyImage2.png" x:Name="Image2" />
        <Image Source="MyImage3.png" x:Name="Image3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Xaml.cs

```
public void OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
    Image1.Visibility = Image1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    Image2.Visibility = Image2.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    Image3.Visibility = Image3.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code and it is simple

```
Image img;
public void OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image uri"));
    gdParentGrid.Children.Add(img);
}
```

Set the height and width accordingly if you want multiple times to add image loop it . Add it to a grid or a stack panel as children.

Comment: Hmm but where I can define the X/Y coordinates where the images should apppear?

Comment: Yes you can in that case you need to sdd the images to a canvas control and set the Canvas.Left and .Right property to the xy co ordinate you require. The other option is use margins if you are comfortable with it :)